# Is there a Knot Theory software to analyze general curves in 3D?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

So I happen to like proteins quite a lot and one thing that is very similar to a protein, when represented as the bare minimum, is a 1D curve embedded in the 3D space. They form beautiful and unique shapes and the particular way in which the curve winds itself matters a lot to the chemistry of proteins in general, which is a HUGE deal for every living system we know of.

So in my burning passion for proteins and math I have done a lot of things to those curves, and one thing I'd like to do now is play with Knot Theory.

What I have in my hands is a collection of points in order (the curve). Usually these polymers are linear, meaning that they have two ends, like a rope, but I can assume they are cyclic and that they fuse together at the ends just for purposes of calculating knot invariants, as if the protein itself was one huge knot. I'm not awfully proficient in Knot Theory, but I'd like to look for patterns in these invariants for my protein database.

What I would like to know is:

Is there a software out there which would help me calculate knot invariants for these curves in 3D space (given that their ends are fused together)?

Comment: A two-ended string could be fused to form any knot. There's no completely natural way to fuse the ends. You have to either add some more string or bend the string to make the ends meet at a single point. You could always do this in such a way that the string ends up unknotted. Maybe you have some canonical way of doing it, though, and I don't intend to deter anyone from helping you find knot software, so feel free to ignore this comment.

Comment: @MattSamuel That's a very nice feedback. I was just thinking that maybe the software would assume the ends were kinda united, since I was looking for a discrete representation, but now that you have touched on that problem, I'd like more feedback on that. Do you have links for me on the subject? Preferably practical/hands-on links along with explanations, not just hard theory because I intend to apply this as soon as I can.

Comment: Wikipedia has a link to "Adams, Colin (2004), The Knot Book: An Elementary Introduction to the Mathematical Theory of Knots, American Mathematical Society, ISBN 0-8218-3678-1" I've never read it, though. I've never looked at any books/papers centered around knots myself.